# I want to update the recorded in data base. I want to send the "employee_id" on clicking save button. so that corresponding 'id' recorded is updated

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the record of the corresponding id that is sent on clicking save button. I tried button tage, input tage and link tage but there is some mistake that I am making, but I don't know where?

This is my form

```
            <form method="POST" action="handle_update.php">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="'.$first_name.'" class="form-control" >
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="'.$last_name.'" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="'.$email.'" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Designation</label>
                    <input type="text" name="designation" value="'.$designation.'" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Address</label>
                    <input type="address" name="address" value="'.$address.'" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Date of Joining</label>
                    <input type="date" name="joining_date" value="'.$joining_date.'" class="form-control">
                </div>
               <a name="update" role = "button" type="submit" href="handle_update.php?ployee_id='.$id2.'">Save</a>  
            </form>
```

Comment: `<a>` doesn't submit a `<form>`, `<button type="submit"...>` does

Comment: but in the button can I send href=userid ?

Comment: No. Just put it into a hidden field of the form

Comment: OK let me try it.

Comment: Or if you prefer it to be a querystring value, you can set the ID in the URL you provide in the form's "action" attribute - if you studied HTML forms properly you'd know that a) a button is used to submit it, and b) the URL it goes to is specified via the action attribute. Make sure you understand the basics of how HTML forms work, before trying to implement a HTML form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `hidden` input field that holds the value you want to submit. Change your `<a>` to a `<button>` that can submit your form. Change your code to:

```
<form method="POST" action="handle_update.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ployee_id" value="' . $id2 . '">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="'.$first_name.'" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="'.$last_name.'" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="'.$email.'" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Designation</label>
        <input type="text" name="designation" value="'.$designation.'" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Address</label>
        <input type="address" name="address" value="'.$address.'" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Date of Joining</label>
        <input type="date" name="joining_date" value="'.$joining_date.'" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="update">Save</button>
</form>
```

More on forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

More on hidden inputs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Comment: Problem solved than you for your time borther.